# Unable to bind ajax data into pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using Django and on pop up, I am displaying user detail I am getting data in the form of HTMLusing ajax and django but I am unable to bind the data into my popup.

my view:-

```
def app_user_by_id(request,user_id=None):
    if request.method == "GET":
        result_data_for_editing ={}
        master_user_types_list = MasterUserTypes.objects.using("cms").all()
        university_all_list = Universities.objects.using("cms").all()
        if request.method == "GET":
            get_user_api_url = userService['getUserDetail'] + str(user_id)
            response_data = create_get_request(get_user_api_url)
            if response_data.status_code == 200:
                print response_data.text
                json_data = json.loads(response_data.text)
                if json_data['data'] is not None:
                    result_data_for_editing = json_data['data']
                if request.is_ajax():
                    html = render_to_string('templates/app_user/user_by_id.html',
                                            {'result_data_for_editing': result_data_for_editing,
                                             'master_user_types_list': master_user_types_list,'university_all_list':university_all_list,})
                    return HttpResponse(html)
```

and the ajax call function:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.getObjectById').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') && $(this).attr('action')) {
            getObjectById(this);

        }
        else {
            alert("id and action is required field ...............")
        }
    });
});


function getObjectById(object) {

    var baseURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '');
    var requestData = {};
    var id = object.getAttribute("id");
    requestData.id = id;
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL+'/appuser/getUserDetailById/'+ id,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("hjwekhkwhekewh");
                var div ='<div ' + '>' + data+ '</div>';
            $("#usergetdetailfromapi").append(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, ex) {
            ajaxLoaderStop();
        }
    });

}
```

There is no problem with ajax call its response is successfull,but i am unable to bind my data into this dropdown:-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">User Detail</h4>
                </div>
                <div  class="modal-body " >
                    <div id="usergetdetailfromapi">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i just debugged my ajax request it is not comming in success case it is going to error fuction.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i have alert pop on success and error case but the success alert doesn't pop up instead error alert pop ups

Comment: Well, what error are you getting? Take a look at your browser console log. Press `Ctrl+Shift+J` and tell us what error message do you see.

Comment: it shows parseerror

Comment: it worked after i remeoved dataType: "json",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was getting parse error its because  i declared dataTYpe="JSON" but i wasnt getting any json data and i remoived dataType and it worked.

```
function getObjectById(object) {

    var baseURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '');
    var requestData = {};
    var id = object.getAttribute("id");
    requestData.id = id;
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL+'/appuser/getUserDetailById/'+ id,
        method: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("hjwekhkwhekewh");
                var div ='<div ' + '>' + data+ '</div>';
            $("#usergetdetailfromapi").append(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, ex) {
            ajaxLoaderStop();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/appuser/getUserDetailById',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { 'id': id },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("hjwekhkwhekewh");
        var div = '<div ' + '>' + data.d + '</div>';
        $("#usergetdetailfromapi").append(data.d);
    }
});
```

here is updated code use it. I think it's work.

Comment: I doubt it will work. The `id` should be a part of the url, that is what the view at the backend expects.